# Map Reduce using Javascript in Hive

Tags: javascript, hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hiveql

I have been using Map Reduce function written in JavaScript in Mongo DB. Now due to Big Data i have to switch to Hadoop and Hive.

So i need to implement HiveQL with JavaScript functions as the map and reduce scripts.

I have read many documentations that there is no language constraint for the script. for reference :- http://dev.bizo.com/2009/07/custom-map-scripts-and-hive.html

When i try to HiveQL with even with this simple JavaScript function as map script

```
function map(data){
    return data;
}
```

i get this error

```
*Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Hive Runtime Error while closing operators
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.close(ExecMapper.java:232)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:429)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: [Error 20003]: An error occurred when trying to close the Operator running your custom script.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ScriptOperator.close(ScriptOperator.java:550)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:610)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:610)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:610)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.close(ExecMapper.java:205)
    ... 8 more*
```

Comment: Can you at least show the MapReduce function?

Comment: function map(element){
 return element;
}   this is the most basic map function i tried implementing. cannot share the actual function though.